# Traversing children's children and adding function to all inputs while keep other children untouched

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now and not sure how to do the following. My form component has children that contain regular html markup as well a inputs. If the child is a Input I want to add the `attachToForm` and `detachFromForm` functions. If it is not an input I want to continue traversing the children to make sure that the element does not have a child input field. Wether or not the element is an input I still want it to appear on my page, I just want to add the functions to the inputs.

The problem is I can only get my function to return only the inputs, removing the labels and title. I know that is because Im only adding elements with inputs to newChildren, but if I push the other elements in the else if section I get duplicates and i can think of another way of doing this. Im not sure if im not understanding basic JS or having a brain gap.

```
React.Children.forEach(children, function(child) {
        var current = child;
        if (child.props && child.props.name) {
            this.newChildren.push(React.cloneElement(child, {
                detachFromForm: this.detachFromForm,
                attachToForm: this.attachToForm,
                key: child.props.name
            }));
        } else if (child.props && child.props.children){
            this.newChildren.push(child);
            this.registerInputs(child.props.children);
        } else {
            *need to keep track of parent elements and elements that do not have inputs
        }
    }.bind(this));
```

Edit: Not sure if needed but this is and example form im traversing

```
return ( 
            <Modal className="_common-edit-team-settings" title={`Edit ${this.props.team.name}`} isOpen={this.props.modalIsOpen && this.props.editTeamModal} onCancel={this.props.toggleEditTeamModal} backdropClosesModal>

                <Form onSubmit={this.saveChanges}>      
                    <FormSection className="edit-team-details" sectionHeader="Team Details">
                        <FormField label="Name">
                            <Input name="name" value={this.state.values.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="text" placeholder={this.props.team.name}/>
                        </FormField>
                        <FormField label="Mission">
                            <Input name="mission" value={this.state.values.mission} onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="text" placeholder={this.props.team.kitMission || 'Kit Mission'} multiline />
                        </FormField>
                    </FormSection>

                    <FormSection className="privacy-settings" sectionHeader="Privacy Settings">
                        <FormField label="Included in global search results" >
                            <SlideToggle name="globalSearch" defaultChecked={this.state.values.globalSearch} onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} type="checkbox" />
                        </FormField>
                        <FormField label="Accessible by anyone" >
                            <SlideToggle name="public" defaultChecked={this.state.values.public} onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} type="checkbox" />
                        </FormField>
                        <FormField label="Secured with WitCrypt" >
                            <SlideToggle name="witcryptSecured" defaultChecked={this.state.values.witcryptSecured} onChange={this.handleCheckedChange} type="checkbox" />
                        </FormField>
                    </FormSection>
                    <FormSection sectionHeader="Participants">
                        {participantsList}
                        <div id="add-participant" className="participant" onClick={this.toggleAddParticipantModal}>
                            <span className="participant-avatar" style={{backgroundImage:'url(/img/blue_add.svg)'}}></span>
                            <span>Add a Participant</span>
                            <span className="add-action roll"><a></a></span>
                        </div>
                    </FormSection>
                    <Button type="hollow-primary" size="md" className="single-modal-btn" block submit>Save</Button>
                </Form>


                <AddParticipant people={this.props.people} toggleAddParticipantModal={this.props.toggleAddParticipantModal} modalIsOpen={this.props.modalIsOpen} toggleAddParticipantModal={this.toggleAddParticipantModal} addParticipantModal={this.state.addParticipantModal} />
            </Modal>
        );
```

As an aside I started out a lot simpler wanting to do the following but get:

> "Can't add property attachToForm, object is not extensible"

If anyone knows why please let me know.

```
registerInputs: function (children) {

    React.Children.forEach(children, function (child) {

      if (child.props.name) {

        child.props.attachToForm = this.attachToForm;
        child.props.detachFromForm = this.detachFromForm;
      }

      if (child.props.children) {
        this.registerInputs(child.props.children);
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging of an error message, you have a problem with immutable `prop` object. Starting from React 0.14 the `prop` is "frozen":

> The `props` object is now frozen, so mutating props after creating a component element is no longer supported. In most cases, `React.cloneElement` should be used instead. This change makes your components easier to reason about and enables the compiler optimizations mentioned above.

[Blog post on this](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#breaking-changes)

So somewhere in your code you try to extend a `prop` object causing an error.

You could wrap different parts of your `prop` interactions with `try..catch` construction which will point you the exact problem place.